# When rendering, fluid and textures do not appear

Tags: rendering

A while ago I looked up 'how to make a nuclear explosion in Blender' and found a few tutorial videos by Iridesium and Raffaele Najjar on how to make them. I followed their directions and added a UV Sphere and a circle and then a domain to make the smoke. After I added some forces and baked the fluid effects, I hit 'viewport render' and was satisfied with the result, but then when I hit 'render animation', instead of a grainy smoke effect, I only got a grainy sphere and a grainy circle expanding, but zero smoke and fire.

[image: How it looks when it renders]

I am using Blender 3.0 and Cycles as my render engine.
I looked up many tutorial videos and they said (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WE0MSG1FHCc) I had to bake a texture into the object to make it appear? But this video uses a box whereas I use a UV sphere (I tried adding an image as a material and then texturing the sphere in UV editing but I still didn't get smoke)?
I attempted many times to see what I did wrong and tried again with many different nodes (from Iridesium and Raffaele's videos) but it did no good, I never got any grainy viewport 'rendered' textures.

[image: The actual explosion]

The one with 0 'Sampling Substeps' is the Circle at the bottom, the one with 2 substeps is the UV Sphere at the top, and the leftover one is the domain.

[image: The one with 0 'Sampling Substeps' is the Circle at the bottom, the one with 2 substeps is the UV Sphere at the top, and the leftover one is the domain.]

[image: Domain]

[image: Sphere]

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't show us any settings you made